# Java: Wildcard Pattern Matching

Tags: java, pattern-matching, wildcard

I have been trying to solve the Wildcard pattern matching and I have found a working solution in the below link:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-character-matching/

I have written an Equivalent java code for the C code given in the above link, which is:

```
    public class wildcard
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        test("g*ks", "geeks"); 
        //test("g*k", "gee"); 
        //test("c*d*", "cad");
}

static boolean matches(String format, String data)
{


    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() == 0)
    {

        return true;
    }

    if ((format.charAt(0) == '*' && format.charAt(1) != 0 && data.length() == 0) && (format.length() != 0 && data.length() != 0))
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ((format.charAt(0) == '?' || format.charAt(0)  == data.charAt(0)) && (format.length() != 0 && data.length() != 0))
    {
        return matches(format.substring(1), data.substring(1));
    }

    if ((format.charAt(0) == '*')&& (format.length() != 0 && data.length() != 0))
    {

        return matches(format.substring(1), data) || matches(format, data.substring(1));
    }


    return false;

}

static void test(String first, String second)
{ 
    System.out.println(matches(first, second)); 
}

}
```

On Execution, a String out of bounds Exception is thrown, which is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at wildcard.matches(wildcard.java:29)
at wildcard.matches(wildcard.java:36)
at wildcard.matches(wildcard.java:42)
at wildcard.matches(wildcard.java:42)
at wildcard.matches(wildcard.java:36)
at wildcard.test(wildcard.java:52)
at wildcard.main(wildcard.java:16)
```

I can see that this exception occurs at the CharAt() method, is there any other way to make this work??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:)

First I noticed that the code **&& (format.length() != 0 && data.length() != 0)** is not on the original code from the page you provide and are causing conflicts with your algorithm so I remove it and it looks like this:

```
static boolean matches(String format, String data) {
    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*' && format.charAt(1) != 0 && data.length() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (format.charAt(0) == '?' || format.charAt(0) == data.charAt(0)) {
        return matches(format.substring(1), data.substring(1));
    }

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*') {

        return matches(format.substring(1), data) || matches(format, data.substring(1));
    }

    return false;
}
```

The problems I talked about are in the second condition you have *data.length() == 0* and in the code I remove was *data.length() != 0*, so that condition was always false because the length cannot be 0 and not 0 at the same time.

I discovered two problems. The first one was that some cases like `matches("ge?ks*", "geeksforgeeks")` end up with having a single wildcard at the format and crashed on `if (format.charAt(0) == '*' && format.charAt(1) != 0 && data.length() == 0)` because of *format.charAt(1)*. To solve this I add the next code to the algorithm:

```
if (format.length() == 1 && format.charAt(0) == '*')
        return true;
```

The other problem was when the format was empty but still have data and solve it with:

```
if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() > 0)
        return false;
```

The final algorithm looks like this:

```
static boolean matches(String format, String data) {
    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() == 0)
        return true;

    if (format.length() == 1 && format.charAt(0) == '*')
        return true;

    if (format.length() == 0 && data.length() > 0)
        return false;

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*' && format.charAt(1) != 0 && data.length() == 0)
        return false;

    if (format.charAt(0) == '?' || format.charAt(0) == data.charAt(0))
        return matches(format.substring(1), data.substring(1));

    if (format.charAt(0) == '*')
        return matches(format.substring(1), data) || matches(format, data.substring(1));

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro (Y)  Works like a charm :):)